# connect two USB ports on the same computer

Tags: usb

I got a school assignment to transfer data from one usb port to the other usb port on the same computer.

I bought a male to male usb cable so I can connect two of my usb ports together.

Can I damage my computer this way?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, but there will be no data transfer possible either. USB *requires* active components to be present. A PC is always a *host* and requires an *USB device* for successful connection.